# ctypes - Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have the task of "wrapping" a c library into a python class. The docs are incredibly vague on this matter. It seems they expect only advanced python users would implement ctypes.

Some step by step help would be wonderful.

So I have my c library.  What do I do?  What files do I put where? How do I import the library?  I read that there might be a way to "auto wrap" to Python?

(By the way I did the ctypes tutorial on python.net and it doesn't work. Meaning I'm thinking they are assuming I should be able to fill in the rest of the steps.)

In fact this is the error I get with their code:

```
File "importtest.py", line 1
   >>> from ctypes import *
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could really use some step by step help on this!

Comment: What version of Python. That works perfectly for me.

Comment: Do you have the `>>> ` in importtest.py? When people post code that has `>>> ` on each line, it signifies that it is being run in the interactive shell. To run it from a file, remove `>>> ` (that's 3 > signs and a space) wherever it appears.

Comment: Don't type the `>>>`s. Those are printed by the interactive shell and should be left out of your source file.

Comment: Well I took out the >>> and I get the same syntax error on line 3:from ctypes import *
print windll.kernel32 #doctest: +WINDOWS
WinDLL 'kernel32', handle ... at ...
print cdll.msvcrt #doctest: +WINDOWS
CDLL 'msvcrt', handle ... at ...
libc = cdll.msvcrt # doctest: + WINDOWS

Comment: Line 3 is not line 1. This probably means you have a _different_ syntax error on line 3.

Comment: i know the basic syntax and how to do class operations, inheritance,etc -- perhaps someone could just explain how to do this "ctypes exports the cdll, and on Windows also windll and oledll objects to load dynamic link libraries.

You load libraries by accessing them as attributes of these objects."

Comment: it would be great to have something that said: take your library, put it here,then do this to use its functions

Comment: @spentak: if you ask for help, provide adequate information. At least show us the last version of code you are talking about. What is on "line 3", for instance?

Comment: my problems were that I had >>> -- that program was just the tutorial sample code-- its functional now, I just don't know how to implement my c library

Comment: @spentak: It's functional now? No more syntax errors? Then post your new functional code. Without it we cant help you.

Answer (score 269):

Here's a quick and dirty ctypes tutorial.

First, write your C library. Here's a simple Hello world example:

#### testlib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myprint(void);

void myprint()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Now compile it as a shared library ([mac fix found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580789/cmake-mac-os-x-ld-unknown-option-soname)):

```
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,testlib -o testlib.so -fPIC testlib.c

# or... for Mac OS X 
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-install_name,testlib.so -o testlib.so -fPIC testlib.c
```

Then, write a wrapper using ctypes:

#### testlibwrapper.py

```
import ctypes

testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/full/path/to/testlib.so')
testlib.myprint()
```

Now execute it:

```
$ python testlibwrapper.py
```

And you should see the output

```
Hello world
$
```

If you already have a library in mind, you can skip the non-python part of the tutorial. Make sure ctypes can find the library by putting it in `/usr/lib` or another standard directory. If you do this, you don't need to specify the full path when writing the wrapper. If you choose not to do this, you *must* provide the full path of the library when calling `ctypes.CDLL()`.

This isn't the place for a more comprehensive tutorial, but if you ask for help with specific problems on this site, I'm sure the community would help you out.

PS: I'm assuming you're on Linux because you've used `ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')`. If you're on another OS, things might change a little bit (or quite a lot).

Comment: @ Chinmay: Can I have a similar code for Windows and instead of C, could you please provide a visual c++ example? I am able to load my library but I am not able to access my functions from the .dll file. It always says "function 'xyz' not found". Could you suggest me a way around this? Cheers.

Comment: I don't know very much about Windows development, but it looks like Windows does something wonky, perhaps it uses a different calling convention? Perhaps you might look up exporting your C++ functions using "extern C"?

Comment: Yes, I did do that but no luck so far.

Comment: For me works only if using `extern "C"
{
void myprint(void);
}`

Answer (score 72):

The answer by Chinmay Kanchi is excellent but I wanted an example of a function which passes and returns a variables/arrays to a C++ code. I though I'd include it here in case it is useful to others.

**Passing and returning an integer**

The C++ code for a function which takes an integer and adds one to the returned value,

```
extern "C" int add_one(int i)
{
    return i+1;
}
```

Saved as file `test.cpp`, note the [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c#1041880) extern "C" (this can be removed for C code).
This is compiled using g++, with arguments similar to Chinmay Kanchi answer,

```
g++ -shared -o testlib.so -fPIC test.cpp
```

The Python code uses `load_library` from the `numpy.ctypeslib` assuming the path to the shared library in the same directory as the Python script,

```
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl
import ctypes

libname = 'testlib.so'
libdir = './'
lib=ctl.load_library(libname, libdir)

py_add_one = lib.add_one
py_add_one.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
value = 5
results = py_add_one(value)
print(results)
```

This prints 6 as expected.

**Passing and printing an array**

You can also pass arrays as follows, for a C code to print the element of an array,

```
extern "C" void print_array(double* array, int N)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        cout << i << " " << array[i] << endl;
}
```

which is compiled as before and the imported in the same way. The extra Python code to use this function would then be,

```
import numpy as np

py_print_array = lib.print_array
py_print_array.argtypes = [ctl.ndpointer(np.float64, 
                                         flags='aligned, c_contiguous'), 
                           ctypes.c_int]
A = np.array([1.4,2.6,3.0], dtype=np.float64)
py_print_array(A, 3)
```

where we specify the array, the first argument to `print_array`, as a pointer to a Numpy array of aligned, c_contiguous 64 bit floats and the second argument as an integer which tells the C code the number of elements in the Numpy array. This then printed by the C code as follows,

```
1.4
2.6
3.0
```

Comment: Similarly, the .cpp file containing `print_array()` needs `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`. Otherwise it is not able to find `cout` or `endl`.

Answer (score 18):

Firstly: The `>>>` code you see in python examples is a way to indicate that it is Python code. It's used to separate Python code from output. Like this:

```
>>> 4+5
9
```

Here we see that the line that starts with `>>>` is the Python code, and 9 is what it results in. This is exactly how it looks if you start a Python interpreter, which is why it's done like that.

**You never enter the `>>>` part into a `.py` file.**

That takes care of your syntax error.

Secondly, ctypes is just one of several ways of wrapping Python libraries. Other ways are  [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which will look at your Python library and generate a Python C extension module that exposes the C API. Another way is to use [Cython](http://cython.org/).

They all have benefits and drawbacks.

SWIG will only expose your C API to Python. That means you don't get any objects or anything, you'll have to make a separate Python file doing that. It is however common to have a module called say "wowza" and a SWIG module called "_wowza" that is the wrapper around the C API. This is a nice and easy way of doing things.

Cython generates a C-Extension file. It has the benefit that all of the Python code you write is made into C, so the objects you write are also in C, which can be a performance improvement. But you'll have to learn how it interfaces with C so it's a little bit extra work to learn how to use it.

ctypes have the benefit that there is no C-code to compile, so it's very nice to use for wrapping standard libraries written by someone else, and already exists in binary versions for Windows and OS X.