# TA-Lib in Ctypes, help calling functions

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So for the past three days I've been trying to figure out getting [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html) to work with python. This is the source I compiled into a dylib (mac version of a .so) and have been calling it from a python script coded as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy

c_float_p = POINTER(c_float)
data = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
data = data.astype(numpy.float32)
data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)


dylib = CDLL('libta_lib.dylib')


value = dylib.TA_S_SMA(c_int(0), c_int(data.size - 1), data_p, 0, 19, data_p)
```

Printing value returns 2, no matter what the array values are. I cannot change the fourth argument of TA_S_SMA from 0 or 1, or else I get a python 138 error followed by a python crash. Can anyone explain to me the proper way to call this function? My C skills are limited (read 0).

Useful links:

- [SMA function source code](http://tadoc.org/indicator/SMA.htm)
- [Tut I used as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081875/ctypes-beginner)
- [TA-Lib source download link](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago and I found these [instructions](http://blog.mediafederation.com/andy-hawkins/getting-ta-lib-to-work-with-python-2-6-swig-interface/). Now they're not using ctypes but it works better in my opinion. SWIG will do all the wrapping for you.  A Couple of things to watch out for.  When you get to the `Single:` `Multi:` sections, if you don't know which on, start with the Multi and if that doesn't work go to the single.  A little further down you'll see he's replacing Python 2.3 to Python 2.6.  I was using python 2.7 and just replaced the 2.6 with 2.7 and it worked.  I'm not sure if this will work for higher versions of python but worth a shot if that's what you're using. Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thanks. Im on 2.7 as well

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [TA-Lib Python](http://mrjbq7.github.com/ta-lib/) project.

It uses Cython to wrap [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org) and is cross-platform, easy to install, and faster than the SWIG bindings.