# ctypes Python dynamic function call

Tags: python, c

I am writing a test script in Python to call C functions using ctypes [ctypes - Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081875/ctypes-beginner)

I have a list of functions and the corresponding shared object names and need to call these functions dynamically using python script.

While I use it to directly call the function name in Python script, it works just fine and prints "hello world" on terminal!

**Python Script:**

```
import ctypes
import os

sharedObjectPath = (os.getcwd() + "/" + "sharedObject.so")

test = ctypes.CDLL(sharedObjectPath)
test.printHello()
```

**C code:**

```
#include < stdio.h>

void printHello(void);

void printHello()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

**However**, it throws an error while trying to use a variable to load the function name:

**Python Script: (Dynamic function call)**

```
import ctypes
import os

sharedObjectPath = (os.getcwd() + "/" + "sharedObject.so")

test = ctypes.CDLL(sharedObjectPath)
fName = "printHello()"
test.fName
```

**Error:**
"complete path"/sharedObject.so: undefined symbol: fName

Any help and suggestions are deeply appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke the function using it's name as a string, you this can do this

```
...    
fName = "printHello"
test[fName]()
```

So the functions name (minus the `()` ) is used to index into the module object and after that it's invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, it solves the issue! appreciate your help