# Using C from Python: How to create a ctypes wrapper

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying this the wrapper example provided on this webpage I've found:
https://pgi-jcns.fz-juelich.de/portal/pages/using-c-from-python.html

I've created a C file called `sum.c`:

```
int our_function(int num_numbers, int *numbers) {
    int i;
    int sum;
    for (i = 0; i < num_numbers; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

then compiled it using:

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o libsum.so sum.c
```

then wrote a `sum.py` file try to call it:

```
import ctypes

_sum = ctypes.CDLL('libsum.so')
_sum.our_function.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

def our_function(numbers):
    global _sum
    num_numbers = len(numbers)
    array_type = ctypes.c_int * num_numbers
    result = _sum.our_function(ctypes.c_int(num_numbers), array_type(*numbers))
    return int(result)
```

and then I wrote a `test.py` file try to call this C functions in python:

```
import sum
print sum.our_function([1,2,-3,4,-5,6])
```

however this error is poping up and I dont know why because I can clearly see
the `libsum.so` in the folder there

> ```
> OSError: libsum.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: test.py is import sum
print sum.our_function([1,2,-3,4,-5,6])

Comment: You need the full path to lisbsum.so ([first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081875/ctypes-beginner#5082294) with my search engine).

Comment: thank you so musch, saved me so much time!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

probably 2 years late.. but..

change

```
_sum = ctypes.CDLL('libsum.so')
```

to

```
import os
_sum = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('libsum.so'))
```

it solved the problem for me