# How to pass the StringBuilder parameter in C# to ctypes in python, which is not the normal ctypes supported datatype

Tags: c#, python, ctypes, stringbuilder

I am working on the project, which there is c# project use the dll like that:

```
    public string GetMachineKey()
    {
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        buff.Length = 128;
        ZwCommDll.GetCPUMachineKey(buff, 128);
        string mk = buff.ToString();
        return mk;
    }
```

and I want do it similily in python use the ctypes.

But i am so comfused by the StringBuilder DataType.

Thanks very much your help.

Comment: You need to add a bit more information to your question. I think you mean to port the C# code to python. I also think you are importing code from a dll, but you didn't specify what dll that may be. You are also referencing `ZwCommDll` but it is not explained where this comes from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ctypes - Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081875/ctypes-beginner)

Comment: The Dll is from anthoer company, I can not tell more info about it.

Comment: The basic ctypes datatype how to pass it I already know it . My problem is focused on the StringBuilder Datatype.

Comment: @wanze Even if the DLL is from another company you should have a header file describing the parameter and return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer()` to generate a writable text string buffer (wchar_t*) for an API.  Use `ctypes.create_string_buffer()` for a writable byte string buffer (char*).  Something like the following should work if the function takes a `char*`:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(128)
>>> ZwCommDll.GetCPUMachineKey(buff,128)
>>> buff.value
b'<returned string>'
```

Comment: Thanks that's should be the answer, if the dll function doesnot have some problem. but here I still got some error. Did you know what's the situation going on?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests\test_dll2.py", line 21, in <module>
    lib_tool.GetCPUMachineKey(buff,128)
ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (84 bytes missing)

Comment: @wanze Use WinDLL instead of CDLL. If you still have issues update your question with your Python code. You should do that anyway otherwise we’re just guessing.  See the [mcve] guidelines.  It would help to see the function prototype as well.