# Unknown option error when installing clang libcxx under OSX10.10?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm-clang

The newest llvm-clang has been installed (I build the source under my ~/ directory).

I was trying installing the standard library libc++.
After successfully executed

`svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx`

I ran

`./buildit`

under
`~/llvm-clang/libcxx/lib`

However, I got an error:

`+ clang algorithm.o any.o bind.o chrono.o condition_variable.o debug.o exception.o future.o hash.o ios.o iostream.o locale.o memory.o mutex.o new.o optional.o random.o regex.o shared_mutex.o stdexcept.o string.o strstream.o system_error.o thread.o typeinfo.o utility.o valarray.o -fPIC -o libc++.so.1.0 -shared -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-soname,libc++.so.1 -lpthread -lrt -lc -lstdc++ -nostdinc++ -std=c++11 -fstrict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-overflow=4

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'

ld: unknown option: -soname

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
 
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSX linker does not know the `-soname` option. There are several workarounds (using `install_name`, delete makefiles,...) see this [What is the 'soname' option for building shared libraries for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637841/what-is-the-soname-option-for-building-shared-libraries-for) and this ["ld: unknown option: -soname" on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580789/ld-unknown-option-soname-on-os-x)

Comment: Thanks. I went through the two references and I think using `install_name` switch might solve the problem. However, I'm wondering how to do that? As the commands are executed automatically, how can I change the flag `-soname` to `-install_name`?

Comment: i do not know MAC OS, on linux there is a makefile (or a file with the build instructions of another builder) in the source code and with the make command you invoke it. In this makefile are also the linker options, so you have to find the makefile and change it.