# “ld: unknown option: -soname” on OS X when compiling Boost

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost, circleci

I want to build Boost from source on different platforms. I've been able to do that on linux (on a docker image). I'm also able to do this on my own computer (Mac OS X 10.13 Xcode 9.4.1) but when I try the same thing on circleci image (using Xcode 9.4.1) it fails with the following error:

It's probably not very relevant but I use cGet to resolve my dependencies including Boost. In this case, cGet is merely downloading Boost and running the b2 command. This is the output:

I am explicitly trying to use GNU compiler and linker and as you can see in the output, toolset is getting passed to the **b2** command properly yet I get the `--soname` name issue. I understand that it can be fixed by using `install_name` but that's something b2 has to fix, right?

[cGet Github Page](https://github.com/pfultz2/cget)

```
Extracting archive /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/boost_1_68_0.tar.bz2 ...
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

using clang-linux : cget : "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++" : 
<rc>
<archiver>/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ar
<ranlib>/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib

<include>/Users/distiller/project/cget/include
<library-path>/Users/distiller/project/cget/lib

;

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build
Scanning dependencies of target bootstrap
-n Bootstrapping the build engine with toolset darwin... 
engine/bin.macosxx86_64/b2

Bootstrapping is done. To build and install, run:

    ./b2 install --prefix=<DIR>

[  0%] Built target bootstrap
Scanning dependencies of target boost
[100%] /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/boost_1_68_0/tools/build/b2 -q -j 4 --ignore-site-config --user-config=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/user-config.jam --build-dir=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build address-model=64 link=shared target-os=darwin threadapi=pthread threading=multi toolset=clang-linux-cget variant=release  cxxflags=-std=c++11 -std=c++11  --layout=system --disable-icu --with-filesystem --prefix=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/pkg/boost/install --exec-prefix=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/pkg/boost/install/bin --libdir=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/pkg/boost/install/lib --includedir=/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/pkg/boost/install/include
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit
    - default architecture     : x86

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - symlinks supported       : yes

Component configuration:

    .
    .
    .
    - filesystem               : building
    .
    .
    .

...patience...
...found 701 targets...
...updating 28 targets...
link.mklink boost/chrono/stopwatches.hpp
mklink-or-dir boost/chrono/stopwatches
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/codecvt_error_category.o
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/error_code.o
clang-linux.link.dll /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.dylib
ld: unknown option: -soname
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++"   -o "/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.dylib" -Wl,-soname -Wl,libboost_system.dylib -shared  "/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/error_code.o"       -fPIC -m64 

...failed clang-linux.link.dll /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.dylib...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_system.dylib for lack of <p/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.dylib...
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/path_traits.o
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/path.o
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/operations.o
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth /Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/clang-linux-cget/release/threading-multi/unique_path.o
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 1 target...
...updated 21 targets...
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/boost] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/boost.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Command failed: ['/usr/local/bin/cmake', '--build', '/Users/distiller/project/cget/cget/build/tmp-00245e52aeba4b19b5a676b97304b3b5/build', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j', '4']
Failed to build package boost
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580789/ld-unknown-option-soname-on-os-x Change from -soname to -install_name

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It happens when trying to cross-compile from linux to OSX without cget involved at all.

Comment: Sadly, no I couldn't figure it out. What I ended up doing to go around my issue was to use GCC 8.

Answer (score 1):

The toolset should be set to `clang-darwin`.